# Nested forms on rails not displaying correctly on Edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

Hi im using Nested_forms gem for a app, everything is working fine.. Im following the documentation [here](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) ...

My form is saving data to database, i can create infinite number of extra fields as i require.

The only problem is when i want to populate the list for example to Edit, then i can´t populate again the list with all the values the user have previously selected, just the 1st value is there , the 2nds select box that should appear, appear transparent.. i leave an image , because english is not my lenguage y probably suck describing it

[image]

EDIT: I think the problem is on the loop , because first time when you submit it look like this..

[image]

And after saving, and lunching the form again to edit. this is what you get.

[image]

Here is the code in there.

```
<div id="nacionalidad">
 <%= f.fields_for :citizens do |citizen_form| %>

    <div>
      <%= citizen_form.label  :citizen, t('generales.citizen')  %>
      <%= citizen_form.select :country_id , Country.all.collect {|p| [ t("generales."+p.iso), p.id ] }.sort_by {|label,code| label}, { :include_blank => true } , { :class => 'pca33' } %>
      <div id="delerr"><%= citizen_form.link_to_remove t('generales.delete') %></div>
    </div>

  <% end %>

  <%= f.link_to_add t('generales.add'), :citizens %>
  </div>
```

And the model

```
class Citizen < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible  :country_id

  belongs_to :player
  belongs_to :country
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be going about this the wrong way.  In my opinion it's much easier to use multiple-select fields and has_many relations.  Then everything just works magically!

Form:

```
<%= select_tag :countries, options_from_collection_for_select(Country.all, 'id', 'name'), :multiple => true %>
```

Model:

```
class Citizen < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible  :country_id

  belongs_to :player
  has_many :countries
end
```

And then if you'd like, you can use another javascript library to make your multiselects more user-friendly:

- Select2: http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/
- ChosenJS: http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Comment: Thanks very very much, the problem with your idea, is that im a noob in Rails, i just need to "fix" this issue on a working app on rails, its a extense register form , on 4 steps, with a lot of code... The problem was just making this gem called nested forms to work properly.. But im sure your advice its what must be done, but i surelly screw the hold app if i try this